# Help with "Uncaught Error: Attempt to modify property "response" on bool"

Tags: errors

A client of mine had me build a site for him. I no longer manager the site, but the client recently reached out to say they received a message from Wordpress that said:

> Uncaught Error: Attempt to modify property "response" on bool in /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bluehost-wordpress-plugin/vendor/bluehost/endurance-wp-plugin-updater/Updater.php:73

I have no idea of what to do with this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. Also including the full text of the error below:

## Error Details

```
An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 73 of the file /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bluehost-wordpress-plugin/vendor/bluehost/endurance-wp-plugin-updater/Updater.php. Error message: Uncaught Error: Attempt to modify property "response" on bool in /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bluehost-wordpress-plugin/vendor/bluehost/endurance-wp-plugin-updater/Updater.php:73
Stack trace:
#0 /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(305): Endurance_WP_Plugin_Updater\Updater->Endurance_WP_Plugin_Updater\{closure}(false)
#1 /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(189): WP_Hook->apply_filters(false, Array)
#2 /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-includes/option.php(1945): apply_filters('site_transient_...', false, 'update_plugins')
#3 /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-includes/update.php(293): get_site_transient('update_plugins')
#4 /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-automatic-updater.php(509): wp_update_plugins(Array)
#5 /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-includes/update.php(729): WP_Automatic_Updater->run()
#6 /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): wp_maybe_auto_update('')
#7 /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#8 /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#9 /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-includes/update.php(256): do_action('wp_maybe_auto_u...')
#10 /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): wp_version_check()
#11 /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#12 /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(518): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#13 /home3/regardk2/public_html/wp-cron.php(138): do_action_ref_array('wp_version_chec...', Array)
#14 {main}
 thrown
```

Comment: BTW, I can access the main admin of the site. No problem, but when I go to PLUGINS section, I cannot view any of the plugins and get the following error: <<There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.>>

Comment: You need to contact bluehost, the error message clearly points at the plugin with the folder name `bluehost-wordpress-plugin`

Comment: Yes. Thank you, Tom. I went in through Bluehost and updated the plugins and all was fine. I wasn't sure what "critical error" meant other than there was a problem. Appreciate your time!